# Get current locale of a thread in another Windows process

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, process, locale

Is it possible to get current locale of a thread living inside another Windows process? Is there a utility that shows this or maybe a Win32 API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locale is stored in the [TEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block), so you would have to be able to open the process with PROCESS_VM_READ rights and the thread with THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION and then call OpenThread()+[NtQueryInformationThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684283%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)([ThreadBasicInformation](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/THREAD_INFORMATION_CLASS.html)) and then get the TEB address in [THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Structures/THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION.html) and read it with ReadProcessMemory().

All of this is undocumented and could change at any time, you also need to handle WOW64 etc...

Comment: And of course, unless the thread is suspended the locale could change right after you have called ReadProcessMemory!

Answer (score 0):

There's no API call for this. Assuming that you can't modify the target app to provide the information on demand, the only solution I can see is a global hook. This allows you to inject your code into the thread in question.

Comment: Yep, I don't have any chance to modify the target app.